# Flyway - not copy sql resources

Tags: java, database, maven, data-migration, flyway

I'm using flyway in my java web project.

My migrations are placed in src/main/resources/db/migration

Now I want to exclude sql resources from the target war so I add to my pom.xml:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
    ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                   <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude>
               </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    ...
    </build>
</project>
```

But then flyway doesn't work because in grabs migrations from the target.

So how could I use flyway but avoid copying sql to my war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to exclude files from copying to the target war instead of excluding the resources from copying to target classes. Here is the way to do it:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <warName>my</warName>
                      <packagingExcludes>**/*.sql</packagingExcludes>
                  </configuration>
             </plugin>
         ...
         </plugins>
        ...
     </build>
     ...
 </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your migrations to separate maven module with `pom` packaging and make your app dependent of this module. You can see example of migration module [here](http://lwandersonmusings.blogspot.ru/2012/07/using-maven-to-integrate-flyway.html)